# What is the sum of a binomial series where the bionomials terms are raised to a power?: $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k}^dx^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, exponentiation, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

We know that:

$$
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k}x^k  = (1+x)^n
$$

Is there a closed-form expression to

$$
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k}^dx^k,
$$
where $d \in \Bbb{R} $? Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: There is pretty much no reason to expect this to have a good formula. Even with $x=1$ and $n,d$ natural numbers, $d>2,$ the closed formula is in terms of special functions.

Comment: For $d=2$ it seems to be related to [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)

Comment: The case $d=2$ and $n$ a positive integer is soecial because then $$\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom nk\binom n{n-k}$$ and our polynomial is the coefficient of $z^n$ in $$(1+z)^n(1+xz)^n$$ But that won’t generalize to $n$ not an integer nor to other $d.$

Comment: Very interesting @ThomasAndrews! Thank you. But actually I really need a general form, n and d not integer.

Comment: I understand, my effort has not been to solve your problem, but to convince you there is probably no good solution.

Comment: As a general rule, just because $$\sum a_kx^k$$ has a closed formula, there is no reason to think $$\sum a_k^dx^k$$ has a closed formula. There is just no mathematical association between these two.

Comment: I see @ThomasAndrews. Thank you!

Comment: This reminds me of a general Hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 4):

Here will be an attempt at a closed form for $d\in\Bbb N$:

You can rewrite it in terms of the [Pochhammer symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom nk ^d x^k=Γ(n+1)^d\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{Γ(k+1)^dΓ(n-k+1)^d}= Γ(n+1)^d\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\prod_{j=1}^d Γ(k+1)\prod_{j=1}^d Γ(n-k+1)}= Γ(n+1)^d\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\prod_{j=1}^d (1)_{k}\prod_{j=1}^d (1)_{n-k}} $$

Which can probably be put into a [Generalized Hypergeometric function form using the following definition](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ//):

$$\,_p\text F_q(a_1,…,a_p;b_1,…b_q;z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\prod_{j=1}^p(a_j)_k\,z^k}{\prod_{j=1}^q(b_j)_k\,k!}$$

Let’s try and find a pattern:

$d=3:$

$$Γ(n+1)^3\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{Γ(k+1)^3Γ(n-k+1)^3}=\,_3\text F_2(-n,-n,-n,1,1,x)$$
$d=4:$

$$Γ(n+1)^4\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{Γ(k+1)^4Γ(n-k+1)^4}=\,_4\text F_3(-n,-n,-n,-n,1,1,1,x)$$

$d=d$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom nk ^d x^k = Γ(n+1)^d\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{Γ(k+1)^dΓ(n-k+1)^d} =\boxed{\,_d\text F_{d-1}(-n,…,-n;1,…,1;x)}$$

where there are a $d$ amount of $-n$s and a $d-1$ amount of $1$s. I challenge you to try the $d\not\in\Bbb N$ case. The formula is surprisingly simple for a hypergeometric function. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Here is an attempt to find a closed form for the following. Instead of writing out the full sum, let’s define:

$$S(n)\mathop=^\text{def}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom nk ^\frac12$$

It is linked to polynomial roots/ values of a trigonometric for $\frac \pi n$ because:

$$S(-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty} n+1+ni=\infty(1+i)$$$$S(0)=1$$$$S(1)=2$$$$S(2)=\sqrt 2+1=\text{Silver Ratio}$$$$ S(3)=1+2\sqrt 3$$$$S(4)=6+\sqrt 6$$$$S(5)=2+2\sqrt{5(3+2\sqrt2)}$$$$S(6)=2\sqrt6+2(\sqrt {15}+\sqrt 5+1)$$$$S(7)=2(1+\sqrt 7+\sqrt {21}+\sqrt 35)$$$$S(24)=2(1+2\sqrt 6+2\sqrt{69}+2\sqrt{506}+6\sqrt{9614}+4\sqrt{10626}+2\sqrt{33649}+7\sqrt{81719}+4\sqrt{156009}+\sqrt{490314}+\sqrt{676039})$$

and so on as the sum gets increasingly larger. Can you find a pattern form for $$S(n)\mathop=^\text{def}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom nk ^\frac12?$$ Notice how $S(7)=2(1+\sqrt 7+\sqrt {3\cdot 7}+\sqrt {5\cdot7})$ and try to rewrite the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Nice and simple ...(after reading it !). I tried for $d=\frac{2n+1}2$ and nothing came. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici trying $d=\frac12$,  $x=1$, and $n=5$ to get a closed form of $\sum_{k\ge0}\sqrt{\binom 5k}=2+2\sqrt{5(3+2\sqrt 2)}$ and $\ \sum_{k\ge0}\sqrt{\binom 3k}+1+2\sqrt 3$ which seem to be linked to polynomial roots. Wolfram Alpha could not find a closed form in it’s closed form generator for $x=1,d=\frac12,n>5$ Maybe you can find a closed form?

Comment: Great effort @TymaGaidash! Thank you. But I'm having some difficult to understand the closed-form from an integer or rational d using the hypergeometric function. As a curiosity, this comes from a transfer function of a dynamic system.

Comment: @VictorSande I put the wrong link in as I tried with another function; it is now fixed.  Please read this [Generalized Hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ//) article. The function is defined for $d\in\Bbb N$. I just put in the $S(n)$ afterwards trying to find a special case for $d=\frac12,x=1$ which cannot really use the hypergeometric function.

Comment: [+1] Impressive.

Comment: Thanks to your "pointer"....